# android videoview scalemode(full screen and normal mode) and keeping orginal video quality

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have used the below code to display videos in  device total screen size.

```
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

But the main problem here is,   video is losing its clarity means the pixels clarity ... But It looks like bug.
Can anyone solve my problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You'd better ensure it is problem of the video size or the player. You may inspect picture size information on PC with any modern video player, like VLC which is available on all major OS.

If the video frame is much smaller than the screen, it is not your fault then.